# Realm JS not writing into schema

Tags: realm, react-native

I am unable to write anything into my schema and there are no errors or exceptions being thrown.

Here's the schema that I have declared,

```
const CollectionSchema = {
name: 'Collection',
primaryKey: 'ID',
properties: {
ID: 'string',// primary key
ItemId: 'int',
Condition: 'int',
Packaging: 'int',
ConditionNotes: {type: 'string', optional: true},
OriginalRestored: {type: 'bool', optional: true},
PricePaid: {type: 'int', optional: true},
AcquiredFrom: {type: 'string', optional: true},
MoreDetails: {type: 'string', optional: true},
DatePurchased: {type: 'date', optional: true},
PrivateNotes: {type: 'string', optional: true},
StorageLocation: {type: 'string', optional: true}
}
};
```

Here's the function where I am writing to the schema,

```
addCollection(){
Realm.open({schema: [CollectionSchema]})
.then(realm => {
    try {
      realm.write(() => {
        realm.create('Collection',
        {
          ID: this.state.ID,
          ItemId: this.state.itemId,
          Condition: this.state.condition,
          Packaging: this.state.packaging,
          ConditionNotes: this.state.conditionNotes,
          OriginalRestored: this.state.originalRestored,
          PricePaid: this.state.pricePaid,
          AcquiredFrom: this.state.acquiredFrom,
          MoreDetails: this.state.moreDetails,
          DatePurchased: new Date(this.state.datePurchased),
          PrivateNotes: this.state.privateNotes,
          StorageLocation: this.state.storageLocation
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error:"+ e);
    }
});
}
```

What is the mistake that I have made?

EDIT:

Here are the dependencies in `package.json`,

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.47.2",
"realm": "^1.11.1"
},
```

Here's how I am creating the ID

```
createIndex(){
let table = realm.objects('Collection').sorted('ID', true);
if(table.length<1){
  return 1;
}
let highestId = table[0].ID;
return highestId+1;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "unable to write anything"? Do you do a query afterwards?

Comment: `realm.write()` will take care of exception handling and roll back if there is one. You can safely remove the `try/catch` block from you code.

Comment: @geisshirt I mean that no data is being written regardless of the number of properties in the schema. I tried `console.log(realm.objects('Collection'));` which does not print any value. Hence I think no data is getting written in `realm.write(()=>{realm.create()})` function.

Comment: What is the value of ID?

Comment: I am using the function `createIndex()` which returns the highest ID that is in the table already and then increment it by 1.

Comment: Your primary key is of type `string` so I will imagine that you get `Collection.ID must be of type: string`. Maybe you should try `int` instead.

Comment: I did try `int` now, but I get the same result.

Comment: Does it happen on both iOS and Android?

Comment: I am not sure about iOS, I only have a PC to try out any program.

Comment: Debugging your code without all the context is hard. If you can reduce it and provide a sample app that demonstrates the problem, then it will likely be trivial to help :-)